# Google Trends HTML downloading Error Page only sometimes? (Google Trends Data Mining)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, data-mining, google-trends

I'm looking to download Google Trends charts via HTML en masse in C#. However, when I first begin downloading the pages, after about 6 successful downloads, they begin to send error pages. I don't believe Google is throttling my downloads since when I look at the web pages in a browser, they show fine. Somewhat confused as to how I could go from it working to it suddenly causing issues...

Here is a look at what's happening. The page on the left is the one with the error page, and the one on the right is the same page in a browser. All words have the same problem where they don't download via code, but in browser they work fine.

Imgur Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxf8n.png

Here is an example URL of a keyword that I'm trying to get the data from (the one from the image):
https://trends.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q=debt&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=300

Here is the code that I use to download the HTML, string url is the same as above, and query would be "debt", again from the URL above...

```
public static void Download(string url, string query)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    try
    {
        webClient.DownloadFile(url, @"C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\StockApp\StockApp\StockApp\KeywordLogs\" + query + "HTML.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + "] Downloaded data for: " + query);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + "] Query:" + query);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
    }
}
```

I also posted this problem on the Brackeys forum, which is linked here:
http://forum.brackeys.com/thread/data-mining-issue-google-trends/

Thanks for all the help in advance,
Elucid

Comment: So after further investigation, it fails after exactly 6 downloads, then stops working entirely for a while...

Comment: Tried limiting connections using ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100; ... Hasn't helped..

Comment: Slowly beginning to find that Google may be the issue, looking into making longer and longer timers to get past their timeout system.

Comment: You are violating their terms of use, so they are blocking you? What a surprise...

Comment: Asking how to violate the ToS of Google.

Comment: Using an export method that they provide doesn't appear to breach the TOS... Simply accessing the HTML as anyone in their browser does and gathering public data that is accessible to everyone.